# Using AWS S3 for Angular SSR storage

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, server-side-rendering, serverless

I am looking into using S3 as part of my serverless environment with Lambda and some others.

I really, really need SEO (so slugs and SSR) and will use `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` in the Angular 13+ app.

How does the SSR work if it gets pushed to S3? Like suppose I had a question and answer site like this site and wanted each "page" of a question with answers to be a URL slug and be part of SSR for SEO.

I need help understanding how SSR works and how to create URL slugs I can send to the sitemap?

New to this type of environmeent and angular but my question "page" willbe a basic component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Angular SSR to work it require Node environment according to this documentation: https://angular.io/guide/universal

You have to start the application using commands like `npm run dev:ssr` This is not possible with S3 setup. You need a **Compute** resource for this to work. You have following options:

- EC2 instance with application installed on it
- Elastic Beanstalk
- ECS + Fargate / EC2 (Dockerised setup) good for long term production setup
- Maybe on Lambda (depends on the site)

Comment: I hear a bunch that you can use Lambda as I want a full serverless ecosystem (I know that SSR violates that theortically) but that is what I am aiming for. I wonder what is the best way to do it on Lambda?

Comment: I got this answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70965742/adding-server-side-rendering-in-aws-lambda-stack-for-angular/71085530?noredirect=1#comment125737260_71085530 but I was wondering how it works in that diagram in that post

Comment: So there are 3 models. 100% SSR, like ASP.NET pages of the last decade. Everything goes to server and you can't do that with S3 type solutions.
100% CSR. This is where Angular shines. Everything is either static or API calls for dynamic content. Maybe You need this one. Host APIs on API-GW+Lambda.
Hybrid (Initial SSR then CSR). React is good in this one.

Comment: I assume Lambda is the best way to do it using like a serverless-framework. Do you know much about that?

Comment: Also would Webpack work for SSR type stuff?

Comment: Yes Lambda is awesome for APIs. For best performance and cost, include CloudFront in your solution. CloudFront+S3 for static content and API-GW+Lambda for your APIs. You can use the same domain for site and APIs via CloudFront.